# How can admin generator modules be enhanced with needed features of Doctrine actAs Versionable?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, admin-generator

We're using actAs: Versionable for one model in our Symfony 1.4 app.  We currently edit this model using an admin-generator module.  The UI gives no indication that versioning is active at all.  I understand how the versions are stored at the database level, but want to know about UI features.

Specifically, are there are any good examples or built-in features we're overlooking to enable UI features to let the user see and compare other versions of the record or even revert?

It seems like such a commonly-needed thing I'm puzzled why I don't find any examples or documentation for those aspects of its use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, ActAs behaviors are not supported by the admin generator.

Nested Sets for example, are not supported as well.  The only way to solve this problem is to code your own handling of the behavior, or find some plugin that already does it and install it.

Perhaps you could entertain the idea of utilizing [Diem](http://diem-project.org/diem-5-0/doc/en/reference-book/doctrine-behaviors).